# Animation with CSS / JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build a simple navbar but I'm having some issues with the way the animation looks and I was wondering if you could give me a hand

I have a Codepen of the issue here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oqYwgP

HTML

```
<nav>
  <div class="menu-icon">
    menu button
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">menu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">menu2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">menu3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
nav ul {
      list-style: none;
      overflow: hidden;
      color: #fff;
      padding-right: 40px; 
      text-align:center;
      height:0px;
      width:60px;
      background:gray;  
  transition: 1s all;
}

.menu-icon {
  width:140px;
  border:1px solid gray;
}
.change-menu-icon{
  background:gray;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.change-menu{
  height: 180px;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".menu-icon").on("click", function() {
    $("nav ul").toggleClass("change-menu");
    $(".menu-icon").toggleClass("change-menu-icon");
     }); 
  });
```

I would like to when I press the menu button for the background color to change and then for the menu to resize, and when I toggle the button again for animation to be reverse, for the resize to happen first and then the menu button background color change.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for either `setTimeOut()` or [**promises**](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You can add a [`transition-delay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay) css property to your `nav ul` css block. You can add this in the [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) shorthand property as well.

I suppose if you want the entire transition to last 1 second, you could set the [`transition-duration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-duration) property of your menu icon to `500ms` with a [`transition-delay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay) of `500ms` like so:

```
.menu-icon {
  width: 140px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  transition: 500ms background 500ms;
}
```

This transition delay will delay the background color transition `500ms` when the `.menu-icon` class does not have a toggled class.

**Note:** I'm using the shorthand [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) here to combine the [`transition-property`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-property) and the [`transition-duration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-duration).

---

Then simply add a [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) css property to your `nav ul` block that includes a `500ms` transition duration.

```
transition: 500ms height;
```

This will allow your `nav ul` to transition without a delay when it doesn't have a toggled class. Therefore, without the toggled classes, your nav will transition first, then your icon.

On the toggled classes, you can specify the delay the other way around i.e. don't add a delay to your icon, but add a delay to your menu:

```
.change-menu-icon {
  background: gray;
  transition: 500ms background;
}

.change-menu {
  height: 180px;
  transition: 500ms height 500ms;
}
```

This way, when you add the toggled classes, your icon will not have a delay, but your menu will.

**Note:**

- For performance reasons (and since you are only transitioning single css properties), I specified the [`transition-property`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-property) on each `transition` css property instead of using `all`.

---

Try the snippet below. I hope it helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".menu-icon").on("click", function() {
    $("nav ul").toggleClass("change-menu");
    $(".menu-icon").toggleClass("change-menu-icon");
  });
});
```

```css
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  padding-right: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 0px;
  width: 60px;
  background: gray;
  transition: 500ms height;
}

.menu-icon {
  width: 140px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  transition: 500ms background 500ms;
}

.change-menu-icon {
  background: gray;
  transition: 500ms background;
}

.change-menu {
  height: 180px;
  transition: 500ms height 500ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div class="menu-icon">
    menu button
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">menu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">menu2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">menu3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: thanks Dan. Now, i dont know if im over my head but what i wanted also was when the menu is open and i press the button for the resize of the menu to go first and then the background color button to change .. just like a reverse animation

Comment: I updated the snippet for this. I'll try to update the explanation, but I believe the snippet is now doing what you'd like.

Comment: @DXXPublic I updated the snippet and the explanation

Comment: Awesome that was exactly what i wanted.

Comment: Great! I'm glad it helped :)